# Oracle Trigger, Queries and If statments

Tags: oracle, triggers

After some reading I found out that you(for some reason) couldn't run simple query statements inside if statements. What I want to do is create a query and check if it's comes back as null or not null:

```
queryResult INT;
SELECT * INTO queryResult FROM Table WHERE Condition;
IF(queryResult IS NOT NULL) THEN
    ...
END IF;
```

Obviously Oracle didn't accept inputting an entire query into an int so is there a way I can define a generic cursor so I don't have to define a specific one for each query (I want to test about 10 of these queries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By NULL you mean the select doesn't return any rows in such case you can use the count function to evaluate

```
queryResult INT;
SELECT count(*) INTO queryResult FROM Table WHERE Condition;
IF(queryResult >0) THEN
...
END IF;
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was out for. Thanks a lot!